# Power BI Matrix/Table visual. Compare values and highlight the greater value

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a data table in which I have a date column and cases. I'm not sure if this is possible in Power Bi, but what I want to achieve is a matrix/table visual comparing values of different years.
For example, compare the values of this year's first week of January with last year's first week of January and highlight the current year's value if it's greater than last year's.

In the attached screenshot below, I have a count of cases in each week from last year. I want to compare the 2022 Jan first week value(618) with the 2023 Jan first week value(577) and highlight the current year's value if it's greater than last year's value.

I want to continue the comparison till the current date. So it goes like the first week of 2022 vs the first week of 2023, 2nd week of 2022 vs 2nd week of 2023, and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First create a week_of_month column using calculated column in dax

```
week_of_year = weeknum(Data[Date])
week_of_first_day_of_month = WEEKNUM(date(Data[Date].[year],Data[Date].[MonthNo],1))
week_of_month = 1 + Data[week_of_year] - Data[week_of_first_day_of_month]
```

[image]

write a measure Highlight

```
    Highlight = 
var val1 = calculate(sum(Data[Score]), filter(all(Data), Data[Month Name] = SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Month Name]) && Data[week_of_month] = SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Weekofmonth]) && Data[Year] = 2022))
var val2 = calculate(sum(Data[Score]), filter(all(Data), Data[Month Name] = SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Month Name]) && Data[week_of_month] = SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Weekofmonth]) && Data[Year] = 2023))

return if((max(Data[Year]) = 2022) && (val1 > val2), 1, 0)
```

Then do conditional formatting using Highlight measure
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey Ashok, thanks for the solution, but if you're manually defining the week numbers, it will have incorrect data. Could this be modified to compare week numbers instead? Like the year 2022, Week 1, with 2023 week 1, the dates should be irrelevant as we're comparing week 1 of the previous year with this year. It could be starting from 1st Jan or 3rd Jan it should only take a full week.

Comment: @ShivamSarin, I modified answer. Calculated week of the month dynamically using calculated column.